# how to cut a css sprite image like this to make an animation?

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations

google shows us a very good example using css sprite to make an animation.

http://www.google.com/green/storyofsend/desktop/#/over-to-google is where you can see how it works(just focus on the envelop).

I just wonder how to make a image like this?
http://www.google.com/green/storyofsend/desktop/assets/images/package.png

It's there any tools helping?

Answer (score 2):

If you already have the separate images, [Compass](http://compass-style.org/help/tutorials/spriting/) will help you to combine them into a single sprite and also generate the CSS classes for it. You could then update the CSS class on your target element to get the animation effect you're looking for.